# Duda para Cerrar Conexion SQL en NODE JS

Tags: javascript, nodejs, mssql

Tengo implementado la siguiente lógica:

```
router.get( '/estudiante', ( req, res, next ) => {
  var sql = require( "mssql" );

  // config for your database
  var config = {
    user: 'martin',
    password: '1234',
    server: 'JMTABORDA-PC\\SQLEXPRESS',
    database: 'school'
  };

  // connect to your database
  sql.connect( config, function( err ) {
    if( err ) console.log( err );

    // create Request object
    var request = new sql.Request( );

    // query to the database and get the records
    request.query( 'select * from Student', function( err, recordset ) {
      if( err ) console.log( err )

      // send records as a response
      res.send( recordset );
    } );
  } );
} );
```

Al traerlo por la URL por ejemplo: http://localhost:3000/estudiante Me lista muy bien todos los estudiantes, pero al volver a refrescar la pagina me sale el siguiente error de conexión:

> Error: Global connection already exists. Call sql.close() first.
>       at Object.connect (C:\Users\marti\Documents\ProyectoFinal\node_modules\mssql\lib\base.js:1591:31)
>       at router.get (C:\Users\marti\Documents\ProyectoFinal\src\routes\estudiante.js:23:17)
>       at Layer.handle [as handle_request] (C:\Users\marti\Documents\ProyectoFinal\node_modules\express\lib\router\layer.js:95:5)
>       at next (C:\Users\marti\Documents\ProyectoFinal\node_modules\express\lib\router\route.js:137:13)
>       at Route.dispatch (C:\Users\marti\Documents\ProyectoFinal\node_modules\express\lib\router\route.js:112:3)
>       at Layer.handle [as handle_request] (C:\Users\marti\Documents\ProyectoFinal\node_modules\express\lib\router\layer.js:95:5)
>       at C:\Users\marti\Documents\ProyectoFinal\node_modules\express\lib\router\index.js:281:22
>       at Function.process_params (C:\Users\marti\Documents\ProyectoFinal\node_modules\express\lib\router\index.js:335:12)
>       at next (C:\Users\marti\Documents\ProyectoFinal\node_modules\express\lib\router\index.js:275:10)
>       at Function.handle (C:\Users\marti\Documents\ProyectoFinal\node_modules\express\lib\router\index.js:174:3)

He intentado implementar un sql.Close(); pero no me aparece.

Agradeceria que me puedan colaborar muchas gracias

Answer (score 0):

Citando al usuario: bams de SO en inglés; recomienda crear un pool de conexiones del modo siguiente

```
new sql.ConnectionPool(config).connect().then(pool => {
  return pool.request().query("")
  }).then(result => {
    let rows = result.recordset
    res.setHeader('Access-Control-Allow-Origin', '*')
    res.status(200).json(rows);
    sql.close();
  }).catch(err => {
    res.status(500).send({ message: "${err}"})
    sql.close();
  });
});
```

[Pregunta original](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44744946/node-js-global-connection-already-exists-call-sql-close-first)

Perfil del usuario

[bams](https://stackoverflow.com/users/8404310/bams)

Answer (score 0):

> Aunque el tema es antiguo daré la solucion para futuras visitas.
>
> En el formato que plantea aunque no es recomendable, se usaría
> .destroy en su caso seria:

```
sql.destroy();
```